# Definition of a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am giving a two part presentation to a class on cardinality. I have done the first part but the prof wasn't satisfied with my definition of a function. For this presentation I have limited time so I want to go through definitions as quickly as possible. For this reason I don't want to talk about relations.

Does this work as a definition of a function:

$$\{(x,f(x))|\forall x \in A, \, \exists ! y\in B \mathrm{\,such \,that \,}f(x) = y \}$$

where A is the domain and B is the codomain? Specifically, does this ensure that everything in A gets mapped to something? Do I have to say that x is in A and f(x) is in B and for all A there exists a unique etc etc?

Comment: You haven't defined what either $(x, f(x))$ or $f(x) = y$ means.

Comment: How bout this: $\{(x,f(x)) \in A \times B |\forall x \in A, \, \exists ! y\in B \mathrm{\,such \,that \,}f(x) = y \}$

Comment: You are mixing things up. In the "set builder notation" $\{x\mid \phi(x)\}$, the property on the right is a property of the object on the left ($x$, in this case). In your example, the statement on the right does not mention anything about the object on the left. Yes, you use $x$ on both sides, but they mean different things: On the left it is a free variable, on the right it is quantified; to say $\forall x \dots f(x)=y$ and to say $\forall z \dots f(z)=y$ is the same thing.

Comment: Since the statement on the right, appearances notwithstanding, does not depend on $x$, whether it holds or not depends only on $f$. But you still have not defined what $f$ is!

Comment: f(x) is supposed to just be suggestive notation for an element of B, in particular, the unique element of B that x maps to. How do I say this? Like this?
$$\{(x,f(x))| x \in A \, f(x) \in B \mathrm{\,and \,} \forall x \in A, \, \exists ! y\in B \mathrm{\,such \,that \,}f(x) = y \}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andres wrote in the comments, you are using $f$ to define what a function is, but the notation $f(x)$ already implies (at least intuitively) that $f$ is a function.

You should write that $f\colon A\to B$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ if:

1. $f\subseteq A\times B$.
2. For every $a\in A$ there exists a unique $b$ such that $(a,b)\in f$.

Alternatively, you could define a function independently of $A$ and $B$ by saying that $f$ is a function if:

1. Every element of $f$ is an ordered pair.
2. If $(a,b)\in f$ and $(a,c)\in f$ then $b=c$.

Then you can add that $f\colon A\to B$ is a shorthand for the following:

1. $f$ is a function.
2. For every $a\in A$ there is some $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$.
3. For every pair $(a,b)\in f$ we have that $b\in B$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything wrong with the standard definition of a function: a subset $S$ of $A\times B$ with the property that for each $x\in A$, there exists a unique $y\in B$ such that $(x,y)\in S$. And given a function $S$, we define the notation $f(x)$ to mean exactly that unique such $y$.

This will probably be more digestible to the audience (in a short amount of time) anyway than trying to write it in symbols. Oversymboling mathematics rarely makes it more understandable to those who don't already understand it.

Comment: This is something that I would put on a handout. But for some reason the prof wanted the set S in set builder notation and I want a more concise way to write it on the board. Also, it would be useful to know how exactly to write this stuff out using set builder and quantifiers and stuff.

Comment: @fhyve: It doen't seem to make sense to demand a definition of what "$S$ is a function" means in set builder function. Set builders are for defining _one particular_ set, but for a definition you want something that you can apply to _any_ set $S$ you want, and it will then tell you whether that $S$ is a function or not. Set builders do not appear to be helpful for that.